# Error in file uploading code

Tags: java, file, jsp, tomcat, file-upload

I am getting following error in jsp page for file upload code:

> The method parseRequest(RequestContext) in the type FileUploadBase is not applicable for the arguments (HttpServletRequest)

error in the code:

```
List<FileItem> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
```

Comment: The method parseRequest(RequestContext) in the type FileUploadBase is not applicable for the arguments (HttpServletRequest)...this is the error message while compiling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [parseRequest(RequestContext ctx)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.html#parseRequest(org.apache.commons.fileupload.RequestContext)) expects `RequestContext` instance as argument but the argument passed is instance of `HttpServletRequest`

Use [ServletRequestContext](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletRequestContext.html) to create a `RequestContext` instance as follows.

```java
List<FileItem> items 
          = uploadHandler.parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(request));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, then found my imports were wrong: the last one of them was using `fileupload` from `sun`, not from `commons.fileupload`. After I **changed them all to `commons.fileupload`**, the error disappeared:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletRequestContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

great answers above, but if you are upgrading to tomcat10 which naming change from javax to jakarta, commons-fileupload as of version 1.4 has not change the naming yet, but you can change to the custom class in tomcat10 instead! (LUCKY ME)

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.ProgressListener          to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.ProgressListener
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload
org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory  to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory

org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem                  to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem
```